# How to disable vscode bracket matching horizontal and vertical lines

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

This is driving me crazy. How do I disable these lines in the editor in vscode?

[vscode vertical and horizontal bracket matching lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI6No.png)

Comment: Search the settings for "bracket pairs".

Comment: You're a life saver mate! This thing was driving me insane! Thanks!! :)